# How to export assets to React Native JS file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've just watched this video on youtube and at 3:20 the guy suddenly exports a bunch of assets into the file without any explanation. Could someone please watch this vid at 3:20 and explain how this guy imports (or exports) all the assets into the icons.js file??

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=diUDjNwZ8Lg&t=203s

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The guy in the video is exporting all the assets as methods of default exported object. You can try [This Explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export), if you that was not help full let me know and find a way to help you better.